# programmatically unset a default application

Tags: android

I made a Home application and I'd like to offer the ability to exit it and unset it as the default application.

Exit is easy (just starting an intent) but the problem is I don't want my program to be launched again the next time the user click the Home button.

I know that this can be done by going in the *parameters / Applications / my app / erase default actions* but I would like to do it from my program so that the user doesn't have to search this function.

How can it be done ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#clearPackagePreferredActivities%28java.lang.String%29) to clear yourself from being the default activity, you cannot clear other activities. This answer may help: [How do I use PackageManager.addPreferredActivity()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583966/how-do-i-use-packagemanager-addpreferredactivity)