# How to show 'Clear Defaults' programmatically?

Tags: android, settings, default

Now i am working on a Home Launcher application.I want to clear defaults of default home launcher(eg: Samsung Home). ie.I want to show `Settings-> Applications->Manage Application->Samsung Home->clear defaults` programmatically.

How to show this through  code?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You should **NOT** do this and instead ask the user to do that action. @DevuSoman

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828224/programmatically-unset-a-default-application

Comment: I think that if you install an app that handles this intent, the OS automatically resets the default, so if even after that, the user chose an app to be the default, you could disable&enable the activity that handles this intent, and it will be reset again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**NOTE:** *Since this question is limited to accessing the Manage Application Settings options, my answer covers just that. You will have to figure out a way of getting the actual Package Name.*

Also, if the idea is to also Clear the Defaults automatically via code, then that, to the best of my knowledge, cannot be done. Someone can correct me if I am wrong on this.

That being said, this piece of code will open the specific application's *Manage Application* screen from your app (the package name must be supplied).

```
Intent showSettings = new Intent();
showSettings.setAction(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
Uri uriAppSettings = Uri.fromParts("package", "THE_APP_PACKAGE_NAME", null);
showSettings.setData(uriAppSettings);
startActivity(showSettings);
```

For example, if the package name of the Google Maps application is `com.google.android.apps.maps`, the replace `THE_APP_PACKAGE_NAME` with it and the code will open the *Manage Application* screen for the Google Maps application.

**UPDATE:**

The PackageManager has a method, [clearPackagePreferredActivities](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#clearPackagePreferredActivities) used to clear the default via code. However, that *doesn't* seem to work in newer Android versions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10246711/450534

Other posts worth reading:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7750187/450534
2. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/Rzv8VU-EUAw

Comment: @DevuSoman: Oh. Cool. Never needed that particular part, so did not know. Thanks. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just for complete the picture, for getting  "THE_APP_PACKAGE_NAME" youc can use something like that :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
 intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
 ResolveInfo resolveInfo = getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
 String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
```