# How to clear my Google map history on 4.0 on button click?

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, intentservice

I'm developing a history clearing application, in which I want to clear my Google Map history.

How can I do this?

```
SearchRecentSuggestions mapsrs = new SearchRecentSuggestions(this.getBaseContext(),com.google.android.maps.SearchHistoryProvider", 1);
mapsrs.clearHistory();
```

Comment: What you can do is try something for yourself first

Comment: but it is cant work brother. this code is cant work on 4.0 @musefan

Comment: @Hiteshpatel: FYI, when you included code you should say what the problem with it is. In this case it is very important to state that it doesn't work in 4.0 and (presumably) higher. Include that information by editing your question

Answer (score 2):

```
 getPackageManager().clearPackagePreferredActivities(getPackageName());
```

FYI for getPackageName() you can give com.google.android.apps.maps

try this ...

Comment: getPackageManager().clearPackagePreferredActivities(getPackageName("com.google.android.maps.SearchHistoryProvider"));

Comment: clearPackagePreferredActivities(String packageName) we'll use getPackageName() if we want to get our app package name. So try with getPackageManager().clearPackagePreferredActivities("com.google.android.apps.maps");

Comment: also same problem. application is stope when i click on button. @Toppers

Comment: oh..but it works fine for me... ok can you checkout with this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583966/how-do-i-use-packagemanager-addpreferredactivity

Comment: dear this is also not work. i m working on 4.0 @Toppers